# Code indistinguishability assumption for Code based cryptography (in special cases)

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory, cryptography

Cryptosystems that are based on error correcting codes are often based with hardness of the two problem.

1. Computational syndrome decoding is hard
2. Indistinguishability Assumption (IA): Distinguishing a code from chosen family from a  random linear code is hard. (or distinguishing a public key from a random matrix of the same size.)

Now consider cryptosystems such as those based on quasi-cyclic matrices eg.BIKE, LEDAcrypt, QC-MDPC. Obviously, one can easily distinguish with high probability a quasi-cyclic matrix from a random one. So, I guess the correction version of this assumption would here be, distinguishing a random quasi-cyclic matrix to one that generates an quasi-cyclic LDPC code. Is this correct?
Secondly, what are the best known algorithms for distinguishing codes that come from a family (say QC-MDPC) to random matrix (potentially restricting it to some structure as said above).  In particular, can we do significantly better than brute forcing?

Answer (score -1):

Even though a quasi-cyclic matrix can be distinguished from a random one, what we're really concerned about is distinguishing a specific structured quasi-cyclic matrix (that generates a low-density parity-check code, LDPC) from a random quasi-cyclic matrix. This is a more accurate interpretation of the IA in this context. The structure inherent in these specific matrices is what provides security.

Here are some references on the topics you mentioned:

**Error-Correcting Codes and Cryptography:**

McEliece, R.J., "A Public-Key Cryptosystem Based On Algebraic Coding Theory," DSN Progress Report, pp. 42–44, 1978. [PDF Link](https://ipnpr.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report2/42-44/44N.PDF)

**LDPC codes and Cryptography:**

J. Proos and C. Zalka, "Shor's discrete logarithm quantum algorithm for elliptic curves," Quantum Info. Comput., vol. 3, no. 4, pp. 317–344, 2003. [Link](https://www.rintonpress.com/journals/qiconline.html#v3n4)

**Post-Quantum Cryptography and Code-based Cryptography (like QC-MDPC):**

Bernstein, D.J., Buchmann, J., Dahmen, E. (Eds.), "Post-Quantum Cryptography". Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. 2009. [Link](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540887010)